# What's the reason that don't use staging buffer?

Tags: graphics, game-engine, vulkan

Recently I was wondering for a game, if there are many models and each one of them needs vertex buffer to draw. Like below three options, which one is most efficient?

1. Create several small vertex buffers and update it with vkMapMemory before draw those models.
2. Create several small vertex buffers and use staging buffer to update.
3. Create several big enough vertex buffers and use it.

Comment: I don't understand your Question title. Also it seems disconnected from the Question content. You also need to elaborate on #3 — it is not clear what you meant; big buffers does **not** somehow absolve you of the need for memory transfers.

Answer (score 6):

You're conflating two different issues... memory management and memory updates.

For memory management, conventional wisdom for both OpenGL and Vulkan is that you want to make few allocations in the underlying API and do memory management yourself, so that you can store multiple vertex data sets in a single buffer at different offsets.  This is critical for being able to do indirect drawing, where you execute a single command to render many models.  Because you can't change the bindings within that command you can only render models that are all within a single vertex buffer.

For memory updates, you need to keep in mind that not all memory can necessarily be mapped using `vkMapMemory`.  Often only system memory can be mapped, while GPU local memory cannot.  The best performance is going to come when the vertex data is on the GPU, so the best practice is to use a staging buffer composed of mappable memory, and then use it to transfer to the real buffer of device local memory.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, using indirect drawing can render many models in one single command, but it's not supported by many platforms.
Is there other options to render many models, especially those models have their own vertex buffers.

Comment: indirect multi draw is supported on all Vulkan implementations as far as I know, and most desktop OpenGL implementations (anything that supports 4.3 and above).

Comment: Really? For example, have you ever tried to query on Qualcomm platform about vulkan support of this feature?